# VPN from a Remote Desktop Session

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

Here's what I'd like to do:  I have a multi-monitor workstation (Vista) at home. I also have a work laptop (XP) with Cisco VPN client 4.8.01.0300.  I want to interact with the work laptop as a window as opposed to just giving it a whole monitor (and keyboard and mouse of its own).

I'd like to remote-desktop into the laptop and then connect the VPN to work, but of course when I connect the VPN the remote desktop session gets closed.

How can I make this work?  Note the home workstation cannot connect to work over the VPN.  It can only be the laptop so that is not an option.

Comment: Why exactly does the RDP session get closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your problem to solve is how to enable LAN access while the VPN is up on your Laptop.

You have to allow this **on the server side** (VPN server/concentrator.). There is an "[allow local LAN access](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2284/products_configuration_example09186a00806f34e6.shtml)" option (split tunneling) you have to enable. This setting overwrites the VPN client setting.

There is a [related (closed) question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124678/allowing-local-lan-access-when-connected-to-a-cisco-vpn). The answer mentions an alternative VPN client in case your sysadmin doesn't want to enable split tunneling.